# Number is int returning False

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I do this:

```
>>> 1 is int
False
```

It returns `False`, even when I would expect it to return `True`. The same behavior occurs when attempting to type-check a variable.

```
>>> a = 1
>>> a is int
False
```

I understand that this has something to do with using `is` instead of `isinstance` or `type`.

```
>>> type(1)
<class 'int'>
>>> isinstance(1, int)
True
>>> type(1) is int
True
```

Could someone explain exactly why using `is` does not work in this case? It makes sense to me **semantically** that it would return `True` instead of `False`.

Comment: You should probably read on the `is` operator. It certainly doesn't do what you believe it does.

Comment: This question is really about that classes are first-class objects in Python, not a question regarding the `is` operator per se, imo.

Comment: @Tobias Not sure, I believe OP is reading the statement `1 is int` as "1 is an integer", which demonstrates a misconception of what `is` does.

Comment: @Tobias it's about huge misunderstanding about what `is` is for.

Comment: Wrote up an answer but couldn't post it.  Make sure not to confuse **is an** with **is**.

Comment: My issue is that it makes sense *semantically* for `1 is int` to be `True`, yet it isn't.

Comment: @Remolten It doesn't make sense, that's why you've been told to read on what `is` does.

Comment: @Apollys I don't see why `is` shouldn't default to the equivalent of `is an` in this case. There's certainly no reason it couldn't be interpreted correctly, though it would cause the `is` operator to have differing usages based on context.

Comment: ... which is a very, very good reason not to interpret it as you want.

Comment: @VincentSavard Fair enough.

Comment: No, semantically, "1 is int" is nonsense.  It's like saying "Skippy is dog."  If you said "Skippy is a dog" that makes sense and is true.  In this sense, python is actually in direct agreement with English grammar.

Comment: @Apollys Good point. Perhaps Python should introduce `is a` and `is an`.

Comment: @Remolten Python did. It's called `isinstance`

Comment: @VincentSavard Specific keywords could be even better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`1` is an `int`, `int` is a *type*.

They can't be equal or be the same object, so `is` is always `False` between those two (`is` checks if the objects are actually the same object).

So this is a question of misinterpreting what `is` checks. The correct way indeed is to use `isinstance` like you did.

Comment: Understood. My issue is that it makes sense *semantically* for `1 is int` to be `True`, yet it isn't.

Comment: yes, natural language vs python ;) same issue with the classical: `if a == 1 or 2:` that we see each week

Comment: @Remolten: It makes sense with the semantics of the English word "is", but not with the semantics of the Python operator `is`.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: `==` doesn't start with a reference comparison (that's the final fallback), and it doesn't involve a type comparison. You can have stuff like `x = float('nan'); x != x`, where the same object compares unequal to itself, or `1 == 1.0`, where objects of different type compare equal.

Comment: @user2357112 totally! you're right. I'll delete my comment. but how can references be equal (final fallback) if the values are different? damn the `x = float('nan')` example is good!!